# create a link in jquery datatable with id from another column

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i'm hoping someone can help me...

I am a little new to jquery and datatables but I have the following datatable that I am able to create a hyper-link in column[1] when the table is rendered using 'mRender' as seen in the examples:

however i would like the 'id' part of the hyper link to come from the 'mData' of column[0] and display the mData associated with column[1] when the table is rendered.

here is my DataTable;

```
var oTable = $('#allCustomerSummary').dataTable({
        //"aaSorting": [[4, "desc"]], 
        "sAjaxSource": '/GetMyDataLink/CustRel',
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "ID" },
            { "mData": "OrganizationName" },                    
            { "mData": "ContactCount" },
            { "mData": "AccountCount" },
            { "mData": "FacilityCount" },
            { "mData": "HasParentOrg" },
            { "mData": "IsParentOrg" }
        ],
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "bvisible": false, "atargets": [0] },
            {
                "aTargets": [1],
                "mData": "ID",
                "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                    return '<a href="/MySite/CustRel?id=' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
                }
            }
        ],
        "sDom":'<p><"pull-left" Cfr>t<"F"i>',
        "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "" },
        "bScrollInfinite": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 15
});
```

Any help would gladly be appreciated :)

Comment: FTI, you're missing a comma after the `}` after `"bvisible": false, "atargets": [0]` I fix it for you ...

Comment: Thanks : i had it commented out before the posting must-a forgot to put the comma back

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `full` argument to the `mRender` function is the entire row's data, so try:

```
"mRender": function (data, type, full) {
    return '<a href="/MySite/CustRel?id=' + full[0] + '">' + data + '</a>';
}
```